# modal component display in angular

Tags: angular

I am checking the source code from https://github.com/angular-in-action/datacenter. I am using this code as is without any changes.
The AlertComponent is a modal component which should be displayed whenever refresh happens, but the content of this component (i.e Date) is displayed directly in dashboard component, so modal component (AlertComponent) is not getting displayed.
If this is working for someone, can you please help on what changes to be done to get this working.

Comment: The code on this GitHub is 4 years old and is based on angular version `5.0.0-beta.6` (latest stable version is 11). The code might be incompatible with the latest version of Angular

Comment: Below versions are used:
@angular/cli: 1.3.2
node: 10.22.1
os: darwin x64
@angular/animations: 5.0.0-beta.6
@angular/common: 5.0.0-beta.6
@angular/compiler: 5.0.0-beta.6
@angular/core: 5.0.0-beta.6
@angular/forms: 5.0.0-beta.6
@angular/http: 5.0.0-beta.6
@angular/platform-browser: 5.0.0-beta.6
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 5.0.0-beta.6
@angular/router: 5.0.0-beta.6
@angular/cli: 1.3.2
@angular/compiler-cli: 5.0.0-beta.6
@angular/language-service: 4.3.6